# Is it possible to list files or directories on a logical volume?

Tags: python, storage, lvm

I have a python script that removes a logical volume. As part of the functional testing, I need to test it's behaviour if lvremove is called when there is a file or directory open, that is stored on the logical volume.

To do this, I want a list of files or directories on the logical volume in order to access one.

Is there any way of listing the contents of the logical volume, in order to access that file or directory when calling lvremove?

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) sounds like exactly what you're looking for

Comment: Is there a bash command that will do the same?